# How to get index value of the arrray which are match with keyword?

Tags: c#, arrays

I try to find the search term in my term collection.

It's my string array

```
[0] "windows"
[1] "dual sim"
[2] "32 gb"
[3] "Intel i5"
```

---

search term is input and return is output

```
search term= "32 gb"                 return -> 2 (position of array)
search term ="android 32 gb"         return -> 2 (position of array)
search term ="android mobile 32 gb"  return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32 GB"                 return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32"                    return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32gb"                  return -> not match 
search term= "dual sim 32"           return -> 1 (position of array)
```

So how can do like this in C#.NET Can any search library or search dictionary provide this feature

My demo code is here :[demo](http://rextester.com/live/FBSGM59372)

My code is :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array= new string [] {"Intel Core i5","5 GB","128 GB"};
    string searchString = "128";//out put is 2 but it's returen -1

    Console.WriteLine(Array.FindIndex(array, x=> searchString.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >=0));

    searchString="128 gb";
    Console.WriteLine(Array.FindIndex(array, x=> searchString.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >=0));

    searchString="intel laptop 128 gb";
    Console.WriteLine(Array.FindIndex(array, x=> searchString.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >=0));       
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return `1`, it returns **`-1`**, since the string `128 GB` is not found in the string `128`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I update my code.How can it's possible with 128 gb

Comment: It works just fine when the `searchString` value is "128 gb": http://rextester.com/MMSEE86197

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen But when  I try search with "128" then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution by using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) and [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx) method I think you will get your desired result:

```
var array = new string[] { "windows", "dual sim", "32 gb" ,"Intel i5"};
string searchString = "32 GB";

 var indexx = array.Select((item, index) => searchString.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower())
              ? index : item.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) ? index : -1).Max();
```

The result:

```
search term= "32 gb"                 return -> 2 (position of array)
search term ="android 32 gb"         return -> 2 (position of array)
search term ="android mobile 32 gb"  return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32 GB"                 return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32"                    return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32gb"                  return -> not match 
search term= "dual sim 32"           return -> 1 (position of array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(Array.FindIndex(array, x => x.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

You were trying to search 128 gb in 128 in your posted code. Correct me if I haven't understood your requirement.

Comment: your solution return me as 0 but i want the position as write in my quetion

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara When I ran I got the result output of 2 when the search string is "128". Please check it again.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : Please try with search term :"laptop 128 GB" and  it's work with my code but when i try "128" then return -1

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara Stop changing your requirements all the time if you want a useful answer.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : i am not change my requirements please check my question care fully.I mention every thing

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara Here its a simple logic. `String.IndexOf()` returns the index of the string. It compares the string match and returns the corresponding value. It checks for the substring also whether it is present in the Parent String or not. In your case `128 gb` is a match but `laptop 128 GB` is not because the `array` does not contain `laptop` as a string in it.

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara your right the requirements are all listed. They just don't make too much sense. `32` and `32 gb` cannot both be substrings of each other

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.FindIndex`

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(array, item => item.Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: Please first see my Demo or refer rextester.com/live/FBSGM59372

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara Why don't you post an answer instead of adding a comment with a link to everyone else's ?

Comment: @ But I have no answer, I want solution.

Comment: Ah sorry - didn't see you were the OP - the above line works as you need it to.

Comment: searchString="intel laptop 128 gb";
   Console.WriteLine(Array.FindIndex(array, item => item.Contains(searchString)));
it;s return -1